# Are $10^{10}$-digit-numbers too big for Lenstra's elliptic curve method (ECM)?

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-curves, prime-factorization

I would like to search prime factors of the numbers

$$10^{10^{10}}-113$$

and

$$10^{10^{10}}+13$$

Both numbers have no prime factor below $10^9$.

Are these numbers still too big for ECM ?

I also tried an improved (?) version of the trial division to find a factor of n :

Produce a long array of random numbers $a_1,...,a_k$. Check, if there are $i\ne j$
such that $\gcd(a_i-a_j,n) \ne 1$, but did not find a factor of one of the above
numbers with this method.

Comment: Why do you think $\gcd(a_i-a_j,n)\ne1$ would be a better test than $\gcd(a_i,n)\ne1$?

Comment: I found this algorithm somewhere, but was not convinced that it is really faster. So, I am not alone with my doubts ... It seems that only good luck leads to a faster answer.

Comment: This question is closely related to two of my other questions, where I ask for prime factors of $14^{14^{14}}+15^{15^{15}}$ and $2^{2^{2^2}}+3^{3^{3^3}}$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On my desktop machine as of 2006, a single ECM curve run on a $10^4$-decimal-digits number with $B_1=11000$ (good for $20$-digit factors) takes more than a minute on a $2.5$-GHz core.

Modmul complexity is worse than $\operatorname{O}(n\log n)$ where $n$ is the digit-count of the operands.

Therefore, my runtime estimate for a $10^{10}$-digit-number gets to more than $2.5\cdot10^6$ minutes per curve on a single core. That's roughly $5$ years. Decide for yourself.

Edit: Nowadays memory bandwidth has increased considerably, but that speedup still leaves the above runtime in the order of several months.